# print is an invalid syntax in python 3

Tags: python

I am new to this and am receiving an error that says print (line 5) is an invalid syntax

```
from random import randint
r=randint
while True:
    s=int(input('How many sides would you like on your die')
    print (r(1,s))
```

Comment: Whenever you get a `SyntaxError` on a line that looks perfectly fine, and even _works_ perfectly fine when you test it in isolation, look at the previous line: you've probably got a missing `)`, `]`, etc. at the end. Eventually you can learn why Python interprets your input this way, but first just learn the rule of thumb and it'll save you hours of debugging and frustration.

Comment: Meanwhile, in the future, when posting an error, show the complete traceback, not just a vague description of the error message. I don't think leaving that off makes your question worthy of a downvote (I'm just guessing at the reason for the downvote…), but it would take this question from "acceptable" to "great".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is not actually on line 5, but on line 4.  You have two `(` brackets but only one `)`.  In search of the final `)` the Python interpreter checks the following line, and only at that point does it raise the error.

Answer (score 3):

```
s=int(input('How many sides would you like on your die')
                                                        ^
```

There is a closing parenthesis missing.